# Circle Graphing Program Null Value Errors (Python 3.4)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

This is my program for graphing circles according to the radius and center coords that the user inputs.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def circle(r,h,k,domain):
    x = np.array(domain)
    y = eval(np.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2) + k)
    plt.plot(x,y)
    plt.show
rad = float(input("Radius: "))
xcen = float(input("Center X Coordinate: "))
ycen = float(input("Center Y Coordinate: "))

circle(rad,xcen,ycen,np.linspace(-10,10,500))
print("Done")
```

When it is run I get these errors.

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Science/PYTHON3/Circle.py", line 5
    y = eval(np.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2) + k)
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Science/PYTHON3/Circle.py", line 13, in <module>
    circle(rad,xcen,ycen,np.linspace(-10,10,500))
  File "/Users/William/Documents/Science/PYTHON3/Circle.py", line 5, in circle
    y = eval(np.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2) + k)
TypeError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eval` is not used for arithmetic evaluation in python, simply remove it from

```
y = eval(np.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2) + k)
```

to obtain a valid

```
y = np.sqrt(r**2 - (x-h)**2) + k
```

also plotting each point as a separate data serie is rather a bad idea, you should create lists of x's and y's and then run.

```
plt.scatter(X,Y) # plt.plot() is used for line plots, not point plots
plt.show() # plt.show is the reference to the function, you need () to call it
```

Comment: I feel stupid. I had eval in there because I took this from another program I wrote a long time ago, where someone would input the entire formula: `y=eval(formula)` `formula = input("Formula: ")`